# How to deal with objects of certain types c#

Tags: c#, list, object, oop

I have a total of 5 classes to which I always create an object.
From this collection of objects a list is created with different types of objects in the list.

```
List<object> objectsEntries = new List<object>();
```

All these objecte have properties that I would like to use.

However, this turns out to be a bit confusing.
Because for each entry in the list I first have to check which type it is.
Then I have to cast the object to be able to use it.

Like this:

```
public void DoSomething(object objectsEntry)
{
    if (objectsEntry is Class1)
    {
        Class1 commandTyped = (Class1)objectsEntry;

        // Now I can use the properties of Class1
        // e.g.
        // Console.WriteLine(commandTyped.Name);
    }
    else if (objectsEntry is Class2)
    {
        Class2 commandTyped = (Class2)objectsEntry;
        
        // Now I can use the properties of Class2
        // e.g.
        // Console.WriteLine(commandTyped.Name);
    }
}
```

But the whole method becomes very confusing and no matter where I want to use the objecte it comes to problems, because I always have to determine the type before and then cast it.

Additionally all classes have completely different properties.

Are there any possible solutions or approaches to this?

Comment: Could all your types (`Class1`, `Class2`, ...) inherit e.g. from a common interface?

Comment: The usual way of handling this type of issue is to create inherited classes.  The instead of having a parameter object in the parameter list is to use an inherited class.  Then you can have multiple DoSomething methods each with a different inherited class in the parameter list.

Comment: And how I can create a List with the different type of inherited classes?

Comment: @gacaba3982 you can implement the same interface for all created classes and after that `List<IYourInterface> list = new List<IYourInterface>()`

Comment: Like others stated, the user-defined classes _must have something in common_ in order to take advantage of their commonalities. The most general approach is to use an interface or a common base type.

Comment: Updated the my question. The problem is that each class has tottaly different properties.

Comment: @gacaba3982 I have updated my answer to emphasize how you could solve it when `DoSomething()` is the only common resource for all your classes.

Comment: @gacaba3982: did any of this helped you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to do this in this way:

```
public interface ISomeClasses
{
    int Id { get; set; }
}

public class SomeClass1 : ISomeClasses
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class SomeClass2 : ISomeClasses
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Main
{
    public void DoSomething(object objectsEntry)
    {
        if (objectsEntry is ISomeClasses someClass)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(someClass.Id);
        }
    }
}
```

Short explain:

- you create an interface with property which you're interesting in
- create few classes which all implements the same interface
- and in yours method called "DoSomething" you could check if object what you have implement the interface and if yes you assign it to variable called "someClass" and you have there access to property which you're interesting in

Answer (score 0):

If you create an interface containing the method `DoSomething()`, you can inherit from that interface in all your custom classes and implement the desired method body of `DoSomething()` for each, e.g.:

```csharp
public interface ISomething
{
    void DoSomething();
}

public class Class1 : ISomething
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"[{nameof(Class1)}] My name is {Name}");
    }
}

public class Class2 : ISomething
{
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"[{nameof(Class2)}] I am {Age} years old");
    }
}

// Other Class* implementations
```

You can then create a list of your interface type and populate it with objects of your custom classes. Calling `DoSomething()` on each entry will then call the specified implementation for the appropriate `Class*` type.

```csharp
List<ISomething> entries = new()
{
    new Class1 { Name = "Sarah" },
    new Class2 { Age = 41 }
};

foreach (var entry in entries)
{
    entry.DoSomething();
}
```

produces:

> [Class1] My name is Sarah
> [Class2] I am 41 years old

Example fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nMaFKE).

Comment: The revision message got messed up, and I cannot seem to edit it. Edit summary for the revision made at 2022-03-05 08:11:12Z originally read _Updating answer to match OP's edit to question post (all classes have different members, but share DoSomething())_.